# Wrap Text in CGContextShowTextAtPoint

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cgcontext, tex

I'm trying to display texts in a CGContext and I want to know how to wrap the texts. How can I make this possible?

Here's my code:

```
NSString *text1 = @"These three first articles describe the God in whom we believe. The pictures of the triangle represents the Triune God), of Jesus Christ and of the dove representing the Holy Spirit are grouped together in order to manifest their intimate relationships and unity.";


- (void) renderPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {


if(index>[images count]-1)return;

UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:index];
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(imageRect,
                                        CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));

NSString *text1 = [script objectAtIndex:index];

char* text  = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 

CGContextSelectFont(ctx, "Arial", 30, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, imageRect, [image CGImage]);


CGContextSetTextPosition(ctx, 0.0f, round(30 / 4.0f));
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1);  
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx,10,10,text, strlen(text)); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more advanced text formatting (like wrapping), use Core Text instead. To display a simple string in a rectangle, use

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
CGPath p = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(p, rect);
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,0), p, NULL);
CTFrameDraw(frame, context);
```